# Eclipse Indigo and m2e and wsimport goal. how to generate ws files in this year 2012

Tags: eclipse, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, m2e, wsimport

Am part of a team building a jsp/j2ee webapp. I decided to use `STS 2.9.2 based on eclipse Indigo` as opposed to every other person in the group as they all use `netbeans` .Every thing was perfect until we reach a stage where one of us was responsible to create some webservices in a maven module which is not a `webapp module` itself. At that point I was unable to run the webapp. it throws this error:

> com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:   The import org.tempuri cannot be resolved

From what I was read from googling either I add additional configuration to the pom or set eclipse to ignore the goal. The first option is out because I really don't want to edit the `pom` because it's not relevant to the team and to the overall project.I am not really sure about the second option.

But essentially the question is how you solve this issue? For the meantime i switched back to netbeans and it seems to be cool but i want to use eclipse